# How do I fix refs heads errors?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repo

git fetch github +refs/heads/n:refs/remotes/github/n
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/n
: git fetch github +refs/heads/n-caf:refs/remotes/github/n-caf
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/movingshadowninja/DU/.repo/projects/kernel/oneplus/msm8994.git'

: export GIT_DIR=/home/movingshadowninja/DU/.repo/projects/device/oppo/common.git

I keep getting this errors how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: It is easier for us to help if you clarify your question a little bit more. Could you add some context?

Comment: ... and perhaps work on the formatting a bit. That's a bit painful on the eyes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm these things:

1. Check the remote repo short name is github by `git remote -v`
2. Check **config** file in **.git**  folder, make sure `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*`

If there still has error, you can clone the remote repo in a different folder, it’s the simplest way.